# Pulling dates into email content using user profile fields

Tags: html, email

I’m trying to populate some dates in an email in HTML based on fields within our user profiles. We have each user profile set with {{expirationDate}}. and I want to be able to dynamically pull that into emails by saying “You have ____ days until your expiration date.” Does anyone know any easy way to do that?

I also want to pull in a date in the form of xx/xx/xx calculated by Now (whenever they receive the email) + 14D.

Unfortunately, I’m not an HTML expert so I’m trying to use any resources I can! Appreciate any help!

Comment: What are you using for your database? If its MySQL all you need to do is add some PHP to subtract dates.

Comment: All our user profile info is housed in iterable which is an ESP.